# Use existing serial heuristic on "Reward Existing Answer" case to remove delay, solving bounty paradox

Tags: feature-request

Consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20033752/294884), note my comment to the bloke ...

Now, the "Reward Existing High Quality Answer" bounty exists for a reason, and that's great. It would seem to me in the specific case ...

1. The A in question is over 3 months old
2. The rewarder and the answer both have accounts more than 3 months old
3. The rewarder has more than 1000 points (ie not a new chum)
4. The action is tracked by the SO software, in relation to the rewarder-answerer user pair, in utterly identical process as ticking or upvoting is tracked.

... the two delays relating to the bounty should be removed.

The first delay is not relevant as the Q is over 3 months old.

The second delay **exists to promote the A on the "featured" list**, so the second delay is not relevant

Indeed, currently any bounties of type "reward superb answer" are pointlessly and annoyingly on the featured list; this age-old paradox and annoyance on SO is resolved.

**Note** I've noticed that the concern "can result in sock abuse" is a common worry for new suggestions on this meta site - and fair enough. If you're thinking this could allow more SERIAL sock abuse, this proposal would use the identical software to the current anti-serial-abuse software. Regarding the **very minor issue** of INDIVIDUAL ACT sock abuse, which can today be achieved perfectly using the good-answer-bounty: it's perhaps better, anyway, to remove the delay as delays help mask laundering in general by revealing impulsive acts (although for example Servy below disagrees with this).

---

Comment: Also, the way I understand the CURRENT serial voting, is that it takes aggregated data... ONE vote won't do much, but ten might... so if instead of ten votes, someone gives ONE 100 rep bounty.... it won't catch it. To me this will CLEARLY lead to more abuse

Comment: @Patrice First off, moving rep from one account to another via bounties, while still abuse, and against the rules, is *far* less of a problem than upvotes between sock puppets.  One moves rep from one account to another, another creates new rep out of thin air, increasing the total.  Next, you'll find that rep fraud using bounties, while it does happen, is quite rare, *much* rarer than voting fraud.  It tends to be *much* easier to manage manually, via moderators, thanks to the fact that it's much less prevalent, and the fact that bounties attract a lot of attention, so it won't get missed.

Comment: @Servy totally with you here. I was just making the point that saying "if the serial voting script caches vote fraud, it'll catch bounty fraud here" isn't fully appropriate since the check for serial voting doesn't trigger on one vote, but in here, one bounty can equal 10-20 votes.

Comment: Hi @Patrice. "will lead to more abuse".  Could you explain that?  That's completely mysterious to me.  If you're my buddy, and I want to send you 100 points ................ I can do it at the moment with the bounty "reward existing" system.  In the new system I propose .....  I would be able to do it with the bounty "reward existing" system.  Explain to me what I'm missing??

Comment: DUDE CALM THE HECK DOWN. I have to answer to you within 5 minutes or I get three comments pinging? JESUS, breathe man, breathe

Comment: not a matter of fast typing. Matter of "I don't owe you answers and I have other stuff to do"

Comment: @JoeBlow My point is that you say "the current script does the job of blocking fraud". My only point here is that the script "hits" when someone does an upvote MULTIPLE times. So for the script to catch and revert, someone gets 10 upvotes (100 points). ONE bounty can be 100 points. So if we let your system go, people, instead of voting 10 times, will send one bounty. Won't be caught, but achieve 100 rep.

Comment: **"Won't be caught, but achieve 100 rep"** well yes, precisely as at the moment in the current system?  Except that if there's no delay, it's more obvious that it is some idiot who created an account to do so, etc etc.

Comment: @JoeBlow So you're proposing removing the delay because you think it's a safe assumption that any bounty granted without using a delay must, by necessity, be voting fraud, and that we should treat every single, "reward existing answer" bounty as fraud?  The existing delays helps *dramatically* to curb fraud by putting so many more eyes on the post.  The fact that there is *very* little of such fraud already means that either this is already working, or at a minimum, is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @JoeBlow I somehow think an AUTO bounty will be less easily seen by the community, where now, if someone does something funky like that, since there is increased visibility on a question, someone might realise "wait, there is a way better answer here, something is funky", whereas on auto bounty it won't be seen by the community as much.

Comment: Hi @Patrice - that seems like a reasonable objection  to the proposal at hand: can you (a) delete your utterly incoherent (no offense :) ) comments above and (b) wouldn't it be sensible to put that in as an answer?  Servy seems to have also quickly thought that up as a reason when I challenged then to give a reason ;-) so that party could upvote the answer, right?

Comment: @JoeBlow a) no, the fact you don't understand or see the logic in it doesn't mean it's incoherent. I believe it should be there, and that's my prerogative b) might be, I don't really care about putting an answer on a feature request since it stands at -8 and likely won't be implemented.

Comment: @JoeBlow I'm saying that the delay dramatically curbs abuse, and your statement that it should be removed because its removal would abuse is completely flawed.  You could, at best, make an argument that it's an unnecessary measure to curb abuse because there would be very little abuse even if there was no delay; it's an assertion you'd have to support, but that one at least has a *chance*.

Comment: @JoeBlow: You posted a feature request. Feature requests invite voting. Those downvotes are from people that feel the proposal should not be implemented **for whatever reason**. They don't owe you an explanation for that. I'll remove all requests for explanations for downvotes as they only serve to clutter up the comments here now.

Comment: Hi Martijn-do whatever you want, it's your site. Of course, obviously, **nobody 'owes'** anything!  I'm trying to find out, whether (a) the sock-danger issue is **INCIDENTAL**, although discussed at length here or (b) the whole entire focus of not wanting this feature: is the sock-danger issue.  By all means, nobody "owes" anything on the site. If you happen to want to delete the comments in question - do so, it's your site. But you're utterly misguided if you're suggesting I was "demanding" an explanation.  Note that the discussion lead to a tremendous clarification of what Servy was saying.

Comment: I don't think fraud is the leading reason as to why bounties aren't instant. Adding additional time doesn't make it any harder to game the system, just more time consuming. By requiring the bounty to be open for a minimum amount of time, we are giving the question (and it's answers!) more visibility, which in turn can result in a much bigger reward than the 100 rep bounty you're trying to give out. I would argue you should leave the bounty open for as long as possible rather than rewarding it as soon as possible to maximize the effect (and to give the community time to weigh in)

Comment: Hi @Kevin .. fair enough.  Thanks for that.  For me the "reward-known-answer" items in the Featured list are clutter; you could say they stop me looking at the Featured list, since, I know that it's often an annoying waste of time: you're not going to get a bounty in the cases where it's a "reward-existing" type bounty.  You could say, whenever one looks at the Featured list, one has to sift out those.  Anyways.  Fair enough ... perhaps this is the reason 13 people have unanimously downvoted this!!  THANKS

Comment: shouldnt your comment be an answer to see if it gets upvoted? (as "the reason"), as should one of the "fraud" reasons be an answer, i guess.

Comment: I dislike the idea of using a bounty to reward an existing answer. but some people feel the need to award a user with more than an upvote for some reason..

Answer (score -6):

## TLDR

I don't like these types of bounties, so I would like for either these types of bounties to go away, or for these type of bounties to be awarded instantly so that I don't have to wade through them. Either option would solve the problem I have with the bounty system.

---

#### Longer version

The delay doesn't prevent fraud, it simply makes it more time consuming. It's more likely that the reason for the delay is to allow the community to view the question and possibly provide more answers, or to rate/contribute to the existing answers before the bounty is awarded.

By requiring the bounty to be open for a period of time, it gives the community time to view and critique the question/answers and/or provide new, possibly better answers to the question.

This of course has a downside: If the question already has an answer that is pretty much as good as an answer for that question can get, that additional visibility isn't really going to do much for the question. However, it can still have a positive effect on the answer in the form of additional upvotes, possibly even more reputation than the bounty you are offering.

---

I do not like this type of bounty, and this is the reason I do not look at bountied questions. Half the time these bounties are put on questions that don't need additional answers, and I find it a waste of my time to go through these questions to find ones that actually still *need* an answer. Sure, rewarding it instantly would fix that, but I don't think we need to be offering/rewarding bounties to questions that don't need additional visibility in the first place. Afterall, that's the purpose of bounties: giving a question additional visibility.

Why give a question additional visibility if it doesn't *need* it.

Comment: very insightful

Comment: I just looked through the first page of 50 featured questions, and only [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700996/optimizing-time-series-generation) of them was placed there for the "reward an existing answer" reason. It hardly seems like you're "wading through" these.